# Properties of a body with spherical symmetry

Tags: mass, symmetry, gauss-law

I'm studing Gauss law for gravitational field flux for a mass that has *spherical symmetry*.

Maybe it is an obvious question but what are exactly the propreties of a *spherical simmetric* body?

> A body is said to have *spherical symmetry* if its density is function
>   of the distance from the center only, and not of the angle coordinate.
>   $$\rho=\rho(r)$$

Firstly does this imply that the body in question **must be a sphere**?

Secondly is it correct to interpret the definition as follows?

For any element of the body of mass  $dm$ and volume $dV$ at a distance $r$ from the center of the body, there exists another identical element $dm$, $dV$ at the same distance $r$ from the center of the body.

Comment: What about the definition is unclear? The density is only a function of the radius, meaning that along spherical shells around the origin the density is constant. That means the body either completely fills any given shell or doesn't fill it at all.

Comment: A note on mathematical terminology: A [sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) $S^2$ is a $2$-dimensional object, while the corresponding $3$-dimensional object is called a [ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_%28mathematics%29) $B^3$. In other words: the boundary of a ball is a sphere.

Comment: From a large distance a cube has spherical symmetry, as does a spherical shell 'hollow planet'.  Possibly a regular tetrahedron or octahedron as well.  The important thing is that X Y and Z axes effects are equal, and interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\rho$ is a generic physical quantity, e.g. mass density in this case, then spherical symmetry is represented in the form of $\rho = \rho(\lvert \vec r\rvert)$ and *not* $\rho = \rho(\vec r)$ with $\vec r$ being the *position vector* of the point at which the quantity $\rho$ is being measured.It is assumed that the center of mass of the distribution coincides with the origin of the reference frame.

So, the body under consideration does not necessarily need to be a spherical surface. For example the electronic cloud in $l=0$ quantum states of atoms have spherical symmetry yet they are not actually spherical with known boundaries.

And regarding your second statement, I would rewrite it in the following more correct way: "For any element of the distribution of mass *dm* and volume *dV* at a distance *r* from the center of the distribution, there exist *infinite* number of identical elements *dm, dV* at the *same* distance *r* from the center of the distribution along *any* radial direction."